# Mockito and PanacheMockito Missing method invocation exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Hello all I'm trying to learn java unit-testing with Mockito and PanacheMock.

I'm getting the following error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

From the following test

```
    @Test
public void testGetAllFruits() {
    PanacheMock.mock(Fruit.class);
    PanacheMock.mock(FruitResource.class);
    FruitResource fruitResource = new FruitResource();

    List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<>();
    fruitList.add(new Fruit());

    Mockito.when(fruitResource.getAllFruits())
            .thenReturn(fruitList);

    Assertions.assertSame(fruitList, fruitResource.getAllFruits());


}
```

The method this test is testing is the following:

```java
    @Path("/fruits")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class FruitResource {
        @GET
        public List<Fruit> getAllFruits() {
            List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (0 == 0) { // terrible bugg
                return fruitList;
            }
            return Fruit.listAll();
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this test so it detected the bugg in FruitResources getAllFruits method?

Comment: I don't get your setup. You try to mock your unit under test (i.e. the resource). What you want, however, is to mock the repository. I recommend reading the [Quarkus guide on Panache: Mocking](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#mocking).

Comment: @Turing85 Ok but how do i mock the repository then? As i understood it from the article you linked the active record pattern does not make use of a repostitory.

Comment: The record is the repository. You mock it by calling `when(Fruit.listAll()).thenReturn(fruitList);`. That is why we needed to call `PanacheMock.mock(Fruit.class);` in the first place so we can mock static methods on this class.

Comment: @Turing85 Alright I understand, but that tests the Fruit entity. Is it not possible to create unit tests for the FruitResource? Are integration tests meant for that? The thing I want to find is the bugg in FruitResources in my post. But I can't find that bugg by testing the Fruit class

Comment: The test tests the `FruitResource`. Within the test, we mock the active record.

Comment: @Turing85 Could you give an example with the code in my post please? I'm having trouble seeing it

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.com/pqgDEdZf no guarantee that it works immediately, however. In addition to this, we can also `verify(...)` that `Fruit.listall()` has been called. You can find an example on the documentation site I linked earlier.

Comment: Ok so if I understand this right. We mock the Fruit class and use the real FruitResource class. This way we don't have to create real fruits but can still test that the class that uses Fruits (FruitResource) still works. Is this correct thinking?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.